# How to install new glibc versions in centos along with existing glib in centos 6.7

Tags: centos, electron, glibc

I want to execute electron app in centos 6.7+ but i wont able to since it raise an error which says,

1. **GLIBC_2.14** not found,
2. **GLIBC_2.15** not found...

i gone through many article.. it says updating glib was not a good method will affect other UI in OS level since Linux is self destructive...

i tested with Virtual Machine updating `glibc into 2.14` which causes Trash folder unusable.. how do i get rid out of it?

is there a way to install glib specific version in `centos 6.7` specific to specific app along with keep existing glib as it is? in my case it is `electron app`.

how to install glibc specific version along with exisiting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple glibc libraries on a single host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host)

Comment: hi @EmployedRussian gone through your answer but it doesnt solve mine...